# Is there an automatic tool that can crawl a live site and generate both a visual sitemap and single-page screenshots?

Tags: website-design, software-recommendation, tools, data-visualisation

Is there an automatic tool that can crawl a live site and generate both a visual sitemap and single-page screenshots?

I tried searching around and all I can find is Powermapper and Slickplan but those don't take screenshots. I am on a Mac.

Answer (score 7):

If you're not afraid of coding you can do this with Python:

```
import gtk.gdk

w = gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window()
sz = w.get_size()
print "The size of the window is %d x %d" % sz
pb = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,False,8,sz[0],sz[1])
pb = pb.get_from_drawable(w,w.get_colormap(),0,0,0,0,sz[0],sz[1])
if (pb != None):
    pb.save("screenshot.png","png")
    print "Screenshot saved to screenshot.png."
else:
    print "Unable to get the screenshot."
```

Reference: [Python: Taking a screenshot](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=448160&s=d65005512ba7666a81dbd8179773d467&p=2681009#post2681009)

If you're on a Mac you could do this with AppleScript:

```
tell application "Safari"
   activate
   set winID to id of window 1
end tell

do shell script "screencapture -c -x -l " & winID
```

Reference: [Applescript - Take Screenshot of ENTIRE Web Page - Safari](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=45871)

If Python isn't your flavor then you could do this with `wget` and there's a good gist write up: "[Use wget to mirror a single page and its visible dependencies (images, styles)](https://gist.github.com/dannguyen/03a10e850656577cfb57#use-wget-to-mirror-a-single-page-and-its-visible-dependencies-images-styles)"

As far as an application I'm not aware I just do mine in the terminal but if I happen to be browsing and I like a site that gives me ideas on another way I could build something I use [Awesome Screenshot for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/Awesome%20Screenshot%20Options?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But would this method show me the connection between the screens or just take screenshots of the whole site?

Comment: it can do both if re-worked